# Wallpaper picker after select Face doesn't set WatchFace Android Wear

Tags: android, watch

On wear side:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager. ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                new ComponentName(this, Class.forName(component)));
        startActivity(intent);
```

This starts wallpaper picker with my watchFace focused, but after click on it remains previous Face

Comment: Unfortunately, now is no possibility to set watch face programmatically